# Install module with puppet

Tags: module, installation, package, puppet

Trying to install the module vcsrepo with puppet, but really unsure how it could be done. The commandline to install it is:

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-vcsrepo
```

Tried to install it this way, but that didn't work:

```
package { 'vcsrepo':
        ensure => installed,
        }
```

Comment: You have most likely installed the module successfully. Wrt. your manifest, you seem to be unsure on how to **use** the module you have just installed. Refer to its [README](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo/readme).

Answer (score 0):

It'd be really helpful to see the error output of the first command as that IS the way one installs a Puppet module. If I had to guess, it probably errored out saying something like `/home/yourusername/.puppet/ does not exist` - by default, when ran by a regular user, `puppet install` will attempt to download the module into `.puppet/modules` in that user's home directory. Running `sudo puppet module install module-name` though by default would install the module system-wide into `/etc/puppet/modules`.

Comment: I don't think @user3270211 is having an issue installing with `puppet module install`, Seems to be trying to install the module with a `package` resource.. which will not install the module.